# vuejs how do I change input value from components

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, buttonclick

I have a `form` which is have hidden input. There is a small list of my data. Just has `title` and `id`. This list created by vue component. I want to click this list items then change to hidden input value. Here is my structure.

`HTML`

```
<div id="v-account-select">
  <form method="post">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <input type="hidden" name="id" v-model="account_id">
  </form>
  <account-select :datalist="{{ json_encode($list) }}"></account-select>
</div>
```

`APP.JS`

```
Vue.component("account-select", {
  datalist: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
  methods: {
    item_id_bind(id) {
      this.$emit("#account_id", id);
    },
  },
  template:
    '<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered">' +
    "<tbody>" +
    '<tr v-for="item in datalist"><td>' +
    '<button type="button" class="btn-link" v-on:click="item_id_bind(item.id)">{{item.title}}</button>' +
    "</td></tr>" +
    "</tbody>" +
    "</table>",
});
```

This is my codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event handler.

```
<account-select @account-change="onAccountChange" :datalist="{{ json_encode($list) }}"></account-select>
```

In your parent Vue add

```
methods:{
    onAccountChange(id){
        this.account_id = id
    }
}
```

And update your component to

```
methods: {
    item_id_bind(id) {
        this.$emit("account_change", id)
    }
},
```

Here is a working example.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component('account-select', {
  props: {
    datalist: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    item_id_bind(id) {
      this.$emit("account-change", id)
    }
  },
  template:`
    <table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered">
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in datalist" :key="item.id">
          <td>
            <button type="button" 
                    class="btn-link" 
                    v-on:click="item_id_bind(item.id)">
              {{item.title}}
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  `
});


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    datalist: [{
      id: 1,
      title: "item1"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      title: "item2"
    }],
    account_id: null
  },
  methods: {
    onAccountChange(id) {
      this.account_id = id
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="v-account-select">

    <form method="post">
      Current Account id: {{account_id}}
      <input type="hidden" name="id" v-model="account_id">
    </form>
    <account-select @account-change="onAccountChange" :datalist="datalist"></account-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is my solution. Sorry I was little bit complicated. Thanks for your help.